# Android volley singleton and ui update

Tags: android, user-interface, networking, android-volley

I have an android network request using the volley library and a singleton class.
Im able to make the network request and parse it (as verified by Log.v statements) however i cannot update my UI.

This is frustrating me because it has previously worked but now it seems that 
execution tries to update the UI before the response and parsing has finished resulting in an no data to pass to the adapter. Even though I've made no changes to the code.

Below is the JSONRequest followed by the complementary code in my recycle view adapter.

```
 public void requestAndParseReleaseList(final Context _context, final FutureReleaseAdapter releaseAdapter){

    JsonObjectRequest jsObReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,_url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.v("parserequest", "started parse method..");

            _releaseList = parseResponse(response);
            releaseAdapter.setReleaseList(_releaseList);
            displayToast(_context);

            Log.v("parserequest", "finished parse method..");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.v("err", "nosuccess");
        }

    });
    mySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsObReq);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class FutureReleaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FutureReleaseViewHolder> {


Context _context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader loader;
MySingleton mySingleton;
ArrayList<FutureReleaseItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


public FutureReleaseAdapter(Context context){
    Log.v("created", "success");

    _context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mySingleton =  MySingleton.getInstance();
    loader = mySingleton.getImageLoader();
}


public void setReleaseList(ArrayList<FutureReleaseItem> newData){
    this.data = newData;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, data.size());
Log.v("updated","changed");
}


@Override
public FutureReleaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.release_cell_layout, parent, false);
    FutureReleaseViewHolder holder = new FutureReleaseViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FutureReleaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

    FutureReleaseItem current = data.get(position);


    holder.titleView.setText(current.title);
    holder.dateView.setText(current.date);
    String imageURL = current.image;

    loader.get(imageURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
    }
}
```

Is there any reason on why this is not updating, the 'Log.v("changed"); always displays after the response is received and parsed so i have no clue why there is never any ui update or how i can get my response to update the ui only once I'm satisfied with the returned parsed response.

The adapter is set in the main fragment onCreateView-

```
public class Home_Screen_Fragment extends Fragment {




private Context _context;
private RecyclerView futureReleaseView;
private FutureReleaseAdapter futureReleaseAdapter;
private JSONHelper jsonHelper;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

private String releaseURL = "xxx.php";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    _context = getActivity();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);

    futureReleaseView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycleSpace);

    jsonHelper = new JSONHelper(releaseURL);

    futureReleaseAdapter = new FutureReleaseAdapter(_context);
    jsonHelper.requestAndParseReleaseList(_context, futureReleaseAdapter);


    futureReleaseView.setAdapter(futureReleaseAdapter);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(_context);
    layoutManager.setOrientation( LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    futureReleaseView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    return layout;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update and try

```
public FutureReleaseAdapter(Context context){
Log.v("created", "success");

_context = context;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
mySingleton =  MySingleton.getInstance();
loader = mySingleton.getImageLoader();
```

}

by

```
public FutureReleaseAdapter(Context context){
Log.v("created", "success");

this._context = context;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
mySingleton =  MySingleton.getInstance();
loader = mySingleton.getImageLoader();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Ive tried your suggestion and it made no difference

Comment: can you tell me where in code you are setting adapter to recyclerview. I don't see it.

Comment: I've figured it out.. very stupid error, was failing to add each parsed item to the list, somehow i must have deleted that line without realising